# Elastic query on flattened field with arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

With reference to the following flattened field named X I want to search for the value of sub-field G where it contains "Hello" and return the value of sub-field A for the corresponding array item.  In this case the return value should be "success".

```
X
[
  {
    "A": "failure",
    "B": ["abc"],
    "C": [],
    "D": 31,
    "E": 0,
    "F": "sdfasdfsd",
    "G": "Internal"
  },
  {
    "A": "failure",
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": 0,
    "E": 0,
    "F": "ghjkfghj",
    "G": "External"
  },
  {
    "A": "success",
    "B": ["Block"],
    "C": [],
    "D": 1,
    "E": 2,
    "F": "fghdfgh",
    "G": "Hello"
  }
]
```

So far what I've managed to achieve is to search for the value of sub-field G and return the value of A but for all the array items.

This is the query:-

```
GET /X/_search
{
  "_source": ["1", "2", "A", "B"],
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term" : { "X.G" : "Hello" }
      },
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the result I'm getting, e.g. I'm getting all the pairs.

```
"X":[
    {"A":"failure",
     "G":"Internal"
    },
    {"A":"failure",
     "G":"External"
    },
    {"A":"success",
     "G":"Hello"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, ou can use nested field type with [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html).

```
PUT nested8
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "X": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
PUT nested8/_doc/1
{
  "X":[
  {
    "A": "failure",
    "B": ["abc"],
    "C": [],
    "D": 31,
    "E": 0,
    "F": "sdfasdfsd",
    "G": "Internal"
  },
  {
    "A": "failure",
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": 0,
    "E": 0,
    "F": "ghjkfghj",
    "G": "External"
  },
  {
    "A": "success",
    "B": ["Block"],
    "C": [],
    "D": 1,
    "E": 2,
    "F": "fghdfgh",
    "G": "Hello"
  }
 ]
}
```

---

```
GET /nested8/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "X",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "X.G": "Hello"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also limit the _source like the following: `"inner_hits": {"_source": ["X.A", "X.G"]}`

Comment: The field is flattened type and not nested type so it is giving me an error failed to create query: [nested] failed to find nested object under path [X]".

Comment: flattened
Better type than daynamic, comes with 7.3 +

pros: unlimited number of fields, all things flattened as its name described.

cons: only support few query: term or exist, no highlight.

Comment: I can't see anyway except `nested` to reach the specific part inside of an array.